# Question about bounded variation and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2n}  & \text{if} \  x=\frac{1}{2n} \\
    0  & \text{if} \ x=0 \\
 0 & \text{if} \ x=\frac{1}{2n-1} \\ 
 \text{and linear otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

can you show that $f$ is continuous but not of bounded variation in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MichaelBurr i have made a partition {0,1/n......1/2,1}

Comment: @MichaelBurr can you please help?

Comment: Can you prove continuity?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i have drwan graph and it shows it is Continuous

Comment: Graphs don't prove anything. Try to prove continuity using definition and include it in your post.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy cool ok can you please show it is not of bounded variation? If you have come here to help me

Comment: According the site's poicy we are no supposed to answer question which lack context. You are supposed to show some effort on your part before posting the question. This is not my policy. I will be glad to show why $f$ is not of BV the moment you show some effort on your part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh okay

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy lol i am stuck in doing this can you help either?

Comment: Linearity of $f$ between $\frac  1{n+1}$ and $\frac  1 n$ makes it continuous at all points $x \neq 0$. Can you prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy limit of f before and after 0 is same as it is linear either case

Comment: Can you show that $0\leq f(x) \leq x$ for all $x$ and conclude that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:For bounded variation, take the partition P:{ 0,1/ 2n, 1/(2n-1),....,1/3,1/2,1}.
V(P,f)=|f(1/2n) - f(0)|+|f(1/2n)-f(1/(2n-1))|+......+|f(1/3)-f(1/2)|+|f(1/2)-f(1)|
=1/2n +1/2n+1/(2n-2)+......+1/2.
=(1/2)*(1+1/2+1/3+...+1/(n-1)+1/n+1/n).                                                                         Clearly right hand side term goes to infinity as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks finally i found something right

Comment: OP is simply refusing to include any effort in the question . It is  not proper to answer such a question.